# ConTeXt project structure: Component not linking to environment via product

Tags: context, document-configuration

Following the ConTeXt documentation [enter link description here](https://www.contextgarden.net/Project_structure) I should be able to use this project structure.

- test.tex

```
\startproject *
\environment test_env

\product test_prod

\stopproject
```

- test_env.tex

```
\startenvironment *

\setuphead
    [section]
    [textstyle=\em]

\stopenvironment
```

- test_prod.tex

```
\startproduct *
\project test

\component test_comp

\stopproduct
```

- test_comp.tex

```
\startcomponent *
\product test_prod

\section{Test}

Blabla


\stopcomponent
```

Now, compiling `test_prod` gives me the desired result. The environment test_env is applied. But if I compile `test_comp` I am getting the standard layout without the setups from the environment file. I need to add a line `\project test` to get the desired results. This is not really a big deal but if I understand the documentation correctly this should work without this nevertheless...

Comment: Use `\project test` inside `test_comp.tex` instead of `\product test_prod`.

Comment: @HenriMenke So the documentation is wrong here? How could I've known?

Comment: The project structure is a bit confusing for me as well.  I'm not sure myself how it works.  I only know that projects are essentially collections of environments, so it seems natural to include the project within a product or component.

Comment: Yes, but I would have thought that if we add the project to the product it will be inherited by the component. At least this is what the wiki indicates. But obviously this is not the case here... Perhaps something to ask on the list...