# ConTeXt: Simple project structure does not open component file

Tags: context, multiple-files

I have a very simple ConTeXt project structure as shown, based off of [the 2013 manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf):

**/main.tex**

```
\startproject main
\environment layout
\product handbook
\stopproject
```

**/layout.tex**

```
\startenvironment layout
\stopenvironment
```

**/handbook/handbook.tex**

```
\startproduct handbook
\project main
\component intro
\stopproduct
```

**/handbook/intro.tex**

```
\startcomponent intro
\project main
\product handbook
Hello, world!
\stopcomponent
```

Compiling intro.tex works as intended, but compiling handbook.tex does not include the intro component as it should. In fact, the log suggests that **intro.tex is not even being opened:**

```
open source     > level 1, order 2, name '../handbook/handbook.tex'
fonts           > preloading latin modern fonts (second stage)
fonts           > 'fallback modern rm 12pt' is loaded
open source     > level 2, order 3, name '../main.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 4, name '../layout.tex'
close source    > level 3, order 4, name '../layout.tex'
close source    > level 2, order 4, name '../main.tex'
close source    > level 1, order 4, name '../handbook/handbook.tex'
```

What do I need to change in my source files to make this ConTeXt feature work as purported?

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489494/context-project-structure-component-not-linking-to-environment-via-product) is a similar question but it has no answers besides a comment suggesting that the documentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**ConTeXt looks for files starting from your current working directory, not the directory of the file you are compiling.**

ConTeXt will only scan parent directories for files instead of in subdirectories. (According to the 2013 manual, this is apparently intended behavior.) However, this means that if you are compiling a project, you have to change your working directory to the source file you intend to pass to the context command. In other words, only `context handbook.tex` inside the handbook folder works. Running something like `context handbook/handbook.tex` or `context ../handbook/handbook.tex` (what I was trying to do in the question) won't find the files properly. This is because, again, ConTeXt won't look in subfolders for files.

In a perfect world, ConTeXt should probably be starting with input file's directory and search upward from there, instead of starting with the current working directory. But for now, you will need to invoke the context command from the same directory as the file.

Note that this system has another side effect: You cannot store components in a subfolder of the product. Products must contain all of their components in the same folder, or components shared between products placed in the root directory of your project.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: If you want to compile using `context handbook/handbook`, then you can change the handbook/handbook.tex file to use `\component handbook/intro.tex`. So, components can be stored in a sub-directory, you just have to pass the full qualified path to call them.

Comment: @Aditya So, it would search first in its own directory for (absolute path) /handbook/handbook/intro.tex, and then, since it doesn't exist, move up a level and try (absolute path) /handbook/intro.tex? Neat. I'll update the answer in a bit.

Comment: No. I believe that when you give path with sub-directory, context does not search in the parent directory. So, a single solution will not work for compiling at both levels.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a bit long for a comment.

You can do

```
mtxrun --path=FOO --script context BAR.tex
```

to run context on `BAR.tex`, located in `FOO`.

Components can be under subdirectories, but then specify the paths via `\usepath` or `\usesubpath`.

Files are looked up at parent directories (I think two levels up, maybe configurable). You can also specify components with a subpath.